# The `this` object is undefined when using promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

In the bellow example, when I am running this code, calling the start function, only inside `_one` function `this` is defined. When continuing to the next function `_two`, `this` is undefined. Any explanation? And how to solve this?
Thanks in advance.

```
'use strict';

class MyClass {
    constructor(num) {
        this.num = num;
    }

start() {
    this._one()
    .then(this._two)
    .then(this._three)
    .then(this._four)
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err.message);
    });
}

_one() {
    console.log('num: ' + this.num);
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve();
    });
}
_two() {
    console.log('num: ' + this.num);
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve();
    });
}
_three() {
    console.log('num: ' + this.num);
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve();
    });
}
_four() {
    console.log('num: ' + this.num);
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve();
    });
}
}


let myClass = new MyClass(4);
myClass.start();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am personnaly using `bluebird` promises rather then native ES6.
This promises perform faster (https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/tree/master/benchmark), have more convinient API and available in both browsers and node.js (http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html)
I am bind `this` value to the first promise in chain - after that your example works well

```
'use strict';
var Promise = require('bluebird');

class MyClass {
    constructor(num) {
        this.num = num;
    }

    start() {
        Promise.bind(this)
        .then(this._one)
        .then(this._two)
        .then(this._three)
        .then(this._four)
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err.message);
        });
    }

    _one() {
        console.log('num: ' + (this.num += 1));
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            resolve();
        });
    }
    _two() {
        console.log('num: ' + (this.num += 2));
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            resolve();
        });
    }
    _three() {
        console.log('num: ' + (this.num += 3));
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            resolve();
        });
    }
    _four() {
        console.log('num: ' + (this.num += 4));
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            resolve();
        });
    }
}


let myClass = new MyClass(4);
myClass.start();
```

I've also changed methods slightly so that you can see progress in `this.num`

Answer (score 9):

Modify the promises chain to this:

```
start() {
    this._one()
    .then(this._two.bind(this))
    .then(this._three.bind(this))
    .then(this._four.bind(this))
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err.message);
    });
}
```

The `bind()` will modify handlers to bind with the correct `this` object (the instance of `MyClass`). You will achieve *the method invocation on MyClass instance*.

Following your initial scenario, the Promise will invoke the handlers (`_two`, `_three`) *as regular functions*, which in `Strict mode` will have `this` as `undefined`.

[See here](http://rainsoft.io/gentle-explanation-of-this-in-javascript/#6boundfunction) more details about `bind()`.

Comment: removing my downvote given the whole rewrite of this answer :)

Comment: @fmsf I was thinking OP is having problems that promises are solved to `undefined`. :) But the problem is in `this` arg.

Answer (score 3):

Your `this` inside the `_two` is undefined because you are loosing the lexical reference. You are passing a function has a callback to another function (the promise `then`). When this function is called you'll loose the this.

You can use bind to set the context of the `this` for the functions being called by the `then`:

`.then(this._two.bind(this))`

Using ES6 you can also use fat arrows to retain the `this`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

`.then(() => this._two())`

Answer (score 0):

You can use arrow functions and call the _two(), _three(), etc... inside them. Doing this, the this will be binded automatically.

```
this._one()
.then(() => { this._two() })
.then(() => { this._three() })
.then(() => { this._four() })
.catch((err) => {
    console.log(err.message);
});
```

Comment: You either have to remove the blocks or add `return` to the functions.